# What does the host name "ww8" stand for in URLs

Tags: hostname

Very rarely, I see URLs with a host name of "ww8" instead of "www" (e.g. http://ww8.aitsafe.com, https://ww8.welcomeclient.com/). Though rare, this appears to be consistent enough for there  to be some sort of logic or history behind this, but I have not been able to figure out what it could be about.

Does anyone know what the host name "ww8" stands for and when it is used? Or is this simply a random peak of arbitrarily chosen non-standard hostnames?

Comment: Maybe related or duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/144323/what-does-the-www8-or-www6-in-a-url-mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a subdomain system to identify subdomains. ww8 means that is the 8th subdomain. This system is used to balance load on the server side